# Codeigniter cron job not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a cron job like this:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/website/public_html/index.php className methodName
```

If I run it in terminal it runs, but outputs nothing. If I pass a wrong method name it runs successfully. If I pass wrong class name it outputs a website 404 error.

I also have a routing which adds "en" into url, for example

```
http://www.website.com/en/home/index
```

could this be the problem?

my settings of config.php are:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the steps to prepare CodeIgniter 2.x for cron-jobs via [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) (command line interface):

**1st:** create a copy of your root `index.php` file and save it in your root as `cli.php`

**2nd:** in your cli.php replace `<?php` with this code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

/* override normal limitations */
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

/* deny direct call from web browser */
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) die('Permission denied.');

/* constants */
define('CMD', 1);

/* manually set the URI path based on command line arguments... */
unset($argv[0]); /* except the first one */
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] =  $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/' . implode('/', $argv) . '/';
```

**3rd:** execute your cron job like this:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/website/public_html/cli.php controller method
```

where `/var/www/website/public_html/` is your server's home directory, the location of your `index.php` and `cli.php`.

**notes:**

for CI 3.0 you find the necessary information [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html)

**database:** you'll need to provide your db config settings in your controller method, as the cron job just executes the controller's method. So it doesn't know anything about any database settings!

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "username_admin";
$config['password'] = "password";
//etc..

$this->db  = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);
```

**debug:** just add a link in your html to run your controller's method like: `index.php/controller/method` (remove that once you website is live)

**source:** very [helpful](http://phpstarter.net/2008/12/run-codeigniter-from-the-command-line-ssh/)

Comment: had no idea you can prevent the script from being executed via the browser with a php command, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way to get codeigniter working under cron job,

You can use curl in cron jobs to execute or run the codeigniter in cron jobs 
Example:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl https://www.domain.com/controller/function
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also run cron file from terminal without `cli.php`.it is not compulsory file.

i am runnig cron from my server using following syntax:
`/usr/bin/php /var/www/project1/index.php controllerName methodName >> /var/log/project1/logFile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me....
-O /dev/null-q command line is used to remove the log file in server...

wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.mani.com/poject-name/index.php/tools/sendPushNotification

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)