# How to load a Codeigniter view from a cron job?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a cron job that needs to email the user.

We use a custom Codeigniter MY_Email library.

We style the HTML emails using a view, e.g.:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$this->_message = $CI->load->view('email_templates/password_change_template_view', $data, true);
```

This works fine from any of our controllers except from the cron job.

So, how do I load a view from a cron job?

Comment: Does your cron controller extend CI_Controller? Thinking something the view depends on isn't getting loaded otherwise. Any error messages in the log file?

Comment: check this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186258/codeigniter-cron-job-not-working/36190095#36190095

Answer (score 0):

create a controller called cron_job and create your function within there and then in your actual crontab hit the function within the cron_tab controller

depending on the complexity of the library you could also just move the library to the model

email model
https://github.com/ddell003/Email_model

Comment: I have a cron controller, it has a variety of functions that gets called multiple times per day. The need to send an email from there is a new requirement. I can load the email library and send emails, it's only when I try to load a view and assign its HTML to the the email message that it fails. This works fine when sending emails from regular controllers but not the cron controller.

Comment: if you dump $this->message do you get anything?