# Cronjob script fails, but works via browser (Zip Archive PHP)

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script that generates large zip files, when I execute it via SSH it works, but the same script fails **intermittently** when executed via cron.

Things I tried:

- Changing paths inside the script, but since it executes via SSH it shouldn't be the issue
- Changing path to the PHP executable inside the cron command (I ran "whereis php" and used the 2 available PHP executable locations)
- Modified file permissions
- Put time limit as **ini_set('max_execution_time', 990000);** and via **set_time_limit (990000);**
- Half a dozen support tickets with the hosting company, but they can't help

Last thing I'm trying right now, which I don't think will help is manually setting a time limit after which the cronjob will fail by including:
**/bin/timeout -s 2 990000** but I think it's useless since normally there are no timelimits, unless I'm missing something.

Log file shows that the script fails after I instantiate an object from class ZipArchive and then try to execute the addFile method.

This is my current cron command:

```
30 4 * * * /bin/timeout -s 2 990000 /usr/bin/php /home/script.php > /tmp/script.log
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I would do: write log to see where the script fails. set the limit to "no limit" ("0" for both functions) instead of value so high.

Comment: is it possible that the first call from your cron overlap with a second cron job ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190095/2275490, this is a setup for the Codeigniter Framework but you might get some conclusions from it...

Comment: If you know where it fails, then are you trying to go to ZipArchive as a indirect path? That usually causes errors.  Here's a test, go to the home directory of the user that runs this and type /usr/bin/php /home/script.php and see what you get

Comment: @Forbs hi, i tried it and it worked. I SSH'd into the server and ran the command right from the folder in which i was (i'm assuming that's the home folder). But running the same command through cron makes the script fail

Comment: There are two reasons, 1) The cron is not using your username, or 2) there are directory permission issues that the cron user cannot write to /tmp

Comment: @Forbs thank you for pointing me in the right direction, i'm going to contact support about it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only solution to make this work is an ugly work, which works great. It's a simple CURL script that executes the file that crontab cannot execute.. Then I put the CURL file in the crontab instead.

So I'm executing the CURL script via crontab, that then goes and executes the script that cannot be executed via cron. It's ugly, but it works..

```
# Open a PHP/CURL session
$s = curl_init();

# Configure the PHP/CURL command
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, "HTTP://YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/SCRIPT.PHP"); // Define target site
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  // Return file contents in a string
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, false);  // Indicate binary transfer
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://google.ca");     // Referer value
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // No certificate
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  // Follow redirects
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);          // Limit redirections to four

# Execute the PHP/CURL command (send contents of target web page to string)

if($run_the_script = curl_exec($s))
    echo "cron executed!";
```

The cron script the the following in the header, it's loose protection against normal users executing the script:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) AND $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) die('Permission denied.');
```

^ Check that the file is being executed by a script that resides on the same IP as the server

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a PHP script works through the webserver but doesn't through the command line interface it's because of a difference in configuration. You could try backing up your current CLI's php.ini and copying your current CGI's php.ini to the location of the CLI one. If you are then able to execute the script correctly you know it's because of the configuration.

Comment: I'm suspecting it's some kind of a bug with the PHP's archive function, because now it's not even executing when I run the command via terminal after I SSH into the server