# How to structure/organise models that usually require userId or accountId (using Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, global-variables

I'm sure this is application design 101 but I'm stuck. I've been searching for answers but am not getting very indepth tutorials to find a similar example to what I'm trying to do. If in fact it's even the right approach, completely open to how I SHOULD be approaching it.

**The issue:**

Having trouble figuring out if all my methods in all my models should accept $user/$accountId, eg:

```
 public function do_something($userId, $accountId, $recordId) {

 }
```

or if I can set this globally somewhere and then just reference the global variable through each method that requires it.

```
 // Set somewhere that can be retrieve by all models, but where/how?
 public function getUser() {

      return $this->User;

 }

 // model specific method
 public function do_something($recordId) {

      $user = $this->getUser();

 }
```

**Here's where I am at:**

My application is built using Codeigniter.

All of the data in the application is user/account specific.

As such most of my models will require either or both UserId and AccountId.

I am using a MY_Controller base controller in the core directory, which all other controllers extend. This sets a variable called $this->User which I can access as needed to get the UserId or AccountId for fetching data from the database that are ONLY from the logged in users account.

I now want to use my already existing methods to process some things using a CRON job.

What is the best way to:

- Set a User Object,
- That can be accessed from any file in the application (Models, Views, Controllers)
- AND that I could set whenever I need to if I was running a CRON job where the user will not be based on the logged in user, but rather performing the same function for 10 different users and looping through say an update query.

Comment: this is a call to use CI session library: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-library, except for the cron job. For the latter see more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190095/2275490

Comment: Yes that is fine for when a user is logged in, but it fails on point 3, when a CRON job is looping through different users performing function on separate accounts.