# Auto insert data after a certain time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following data:

```
$purchase_date = 2017-08-20 
$duration = 6 [months]
$expire_date = 2018-02-20
```

I need to run an insert query after every one month from the purchase date till the expire date.
I cannot understand, how could I solve this probleme.

Comment: Does your hosting provider support cron jobs?

Comment: You need to set-up a CRON job on your server, that will execute a PHP script at a frequency you choose (every day at 00:00 perhaps?) In this script, query the items that need to be updated and do what you need to do.

Comment: I've a detailed answer on how to integrate cron-jobs with Codeigniter 2.x and 3.x here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190095/2275490

Comment: also this is an important read: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/cli.html