# cronjob is not running with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, curl, cpanel

This is my cronjob command. I am using codeigniter.

```
curl -s https://duainternational.com.pk/update_system/employee/test_notification >/dev/null 2>&1
```

```
cron time

M   H   D   M   Weekday
5   *   *   *   *
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot get the cronjob running

Comment: how exactly is this related to `php`? and: have you tried sending the output of your command to a file and look at it? and: where's your crontab-entry?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann guide me what exactly are you trying to say. 
if i run this url manually, it works, crontab entry is set to 1 minute?

Comment: check my answer here, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190095/2275490

Comment: remove `2>&1` from the cron job to get an error protocol (usually a mail) on errors.

Comment: @Wiimm here is the thing, i want to send desktop notifications to all the users who allowed the notifications from this site. and in this cron, i am echoing the javascript notification functionality, but its not working, see the screen www.screencast.com/t/L3tRedumX

Comment: But that is not the error message.

Answer (score 1):

On cron job, paths are not known. So, prefix `curl` with its path.

If curl is in `/usr/bin/`, you shoul write:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s https://example.com/ >/dev/null 2>&1`
```

Comment: not working, is that possible if there is an issue from domain service provider side?

Comment: Did you try to log output instead of redirect it on `/dev/null` ?

Comment: yes i tried, here is the thing, i want to send desktop notifications to all the users who allowed the notifications from this site. and in this cron, i am echoing the javascript notification functionality, so its not working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to run a `controller/method/argument` on CodeIgniter then try using command line interface (CLI). ([Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html))

You need to supply the full system path to CodeIgniter's `index.php` file. I'm making assumptions about that path. Substitute your systems path to `index.php`.

```
php /var/www/website/public_html/index.php update_system/employee test_notification
```

Other assumptions I'm making are that the `employee` controller is on this path `/application/controllers/update_system/` and the method you want to run is `test_notification`.

Know that when using the CLI you cannot use the session class. If you attempt to use sessions the CLI request will fail.