# Cron command in codeigniterphp not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have a cron command like this, running every day:

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php56 / home/h2fi/smartreseller.h2fi.com/admin/clients/getclientorderdetails
```

It does not run.

Comment: What is your domain URL ? Also, what is the purpose of admin as you mentioned in the comment URL

Comment: Try this hope this will work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186258/codeigniter-cron-job-not-working