# Cron job is not working in other Controller CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have a CRON job which has some update functionality with my database. I am using codeigniter 3 in my web app. The problem is when I try to fire the cron job using other controller(except the default controller with index method) its not working but if I change the cron job command to my default controller with index method it works normally. I searched a lot of article regarding how to run cron job in codeigniter controller, everyone suggest me to use default controller with the index method as my cron command. But my problem is here I'm not allowed to use my default controller as my CRON command. I'll be highly obliged if anyone can help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

My present command which is working :
`/usr/bin/php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/example.com/index.php Welcome index`
here **Welcome** is my default controller and **index** is main method.

The code I want to use but not working:
`/usr/bin/php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/example.com/index.php Game index`
OR
`/usr/bin/php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/example.com/index.php Welcome startgame`

I'm using GoDaddy Server.

Comment: first, did you verify if it does work, when NOT using cron job? just to double check: `example.com/index.php/game`

Comment: Yes, without cron job its working

Comment: have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190095/2275490, that works for me: `/usr/bin/php /var/www/website/public_html/index.php controller method`

Comment: I am using godaddy share hosting.... how can I use ```user/bin/php/var/``` in my code?

Comment: I use ```/usr/bin/php /var/www/website/public_html/index.php controller method``` but it only works on default controller index method.

Comment: Does it output any message?

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party cron job provider for my projects.