# Cron job not running at specific time, but runs every min

Tags: cron, cpanel

I have developed the project in CodeIgniter (PHP Framework), I have a created model to insert records in the database.

If I set the following cronjob using a cpanel and call it every minute then it works perfectly.
`* * * * * wget https://domainname.com/controller_name/function_name`

But if I set the cronjob for a specific time, which is supposed to be 2.00 PM every day. Then it is not working.
`0 14 * * * wget https://domainname.com/controller_name/function_name`

Comment: Not working in what way? Doesn't get executed at all or maybe tries to execute but fails with an error?

Comment: execute your cron job with this command:

`/usr/bin/php /var/www/website/public_html/index.php controller method`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190095/2275490, hope that helps...