# How to send a CodeIgniter email via Cron Job

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have been trying to send an email message to my user via cron job but every time the cron performs its duty I get the following message as a response:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
```

**I don't understand what that is but here is the code. I want the cron job to run**

```
<?php
class Cron_email extends CI_Controller{
    private $CI;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI   =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->model('Action');
        $this->CI->load->model('Admin_db');
    }
    public function system_auto_calculate(){
       
       $this->CI->load->library('email');

       $site_email = $this->CI->Admin_db->get_site_email();
       $get_site_name = $this->CI->Admin_db->get_site_name();
       $get_site_g_name = $this->CI->Admin_db->get_site_g_name();
       $get_site_g_pass = $this->CI->Admin_db->get_site_g_pass();

       $current_domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

       $config =array(
            'protocol'=> 'ssmtp',
            'smtp_host'    => 'ssl://ssmtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port'    => '465',
            'smtp_timeout' => '7',
            'smtp_user'    => $get_site_g_name,
            'smtp_pass'    => $get_site_g_pass,
            'charset'    => 'utf-8',
            'newline'    => "\r\n",
            'mailtype' => 'html', // or html
            'validation' => FALSE); // bool whether to validate email or not      


        $this->CI->email->set_mailtype("html");
        $this->CI->load->initialize($config);

        $result = $this->CI->Admin_db->get_all_unread_message_by_limit_200();
        if(is_array($result)){
           foreach($result as $row){
                $this->CI->email->clear();
                $id = $row['id'];
                $sender = $row['sender'];
                $receiver = $row['reciever'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $message = $row['message'];
                $time = $row['time'];
                $date_created = $row['date_created'];
                $email_status = $row['email_status'];

                /**==========================Now Send Message**/
                $subject = $get_site_name.' | '.$title;
                $to = $receiver;

                $data['title'] = $title;
                $data['message'] = $message;
                // $data['link'] = $link;
                // $data['link_title'] = $link_title;

                $this->CI->email->from("$site_email", $get_site_name);
                $this->CI->email->to($to); 
                $this->CI->email->subject($subject);
                $body   =$this->CI->load->view('master_4',$data,TRUE);
                $this->CI->email->message($body);  
                if($this->CI->email->send()){
                    //set email status to send
                    $this->CI->Admin_db->reset_user_email_status($reciever);
                }
                
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**Here is my cron job command**

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/curl "https://{domain.com}/Cron_email/system_auto_calculate"
```

I have switched servers and also hosted the file on a different server but the issue persists, but according to support from my hosting register, they said:

> I have double-checked the issue with the tech support team. There are
> no issues on the server-side, according to the logs, and there are no
> error logs in the cPanel itself. The issue is connected to the coding
> of the scripts for the cron jobs.

Please, what am I not doing well?

Comment: please read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190095/2275490, this was mainly focused on CI 2.0, but maybe it helps anyway, as well as using the server's directory instead of the url

Comment: @Vickel, thanks for your comment
thanks so much, have been able to make it work, the issue was that i was using gmail as the sender instead of the domain hosting email 

everyting its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that your emails are not being sent? I see that you reset the receiver email status (whatever that means) though `Admin_db->reset_user_email_status()`, can you confirm it was not done?

If something goes wrong on the sending email level, there is a [printDebugger](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#printDebugger) method that could give more details.

The output from cron doesn't seem incorrect as you are using `curl` to run your controller, which itself should be treated as security gap. If someone will know your url and there will be a lot of emails to send, it could be run dozens of times and your server can be banished as the one which tries to send too many emails at once.

Please read the [CodeIgniter documentation on running controller actions via CLI](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/cli/cli.html).

Comment: thanks so much, have been able to make it work, the issue was that i was using gmail as the sender instead of the domain hosting email 

everyting its working fine now